# Question about the verb 「嗅ぐ」

Tags: words, て-form, manga

Here is the sentence containing the verb in て-form.

> ひさしぶりに　この本皮のグローブがしっとりと敵の血をすって　なんともいえねえ　においを**かがして**くれる....

As my understanding, the pattern てくれる use て-form verb which the verb would be 嗅{か}いで.

Is the verb 「かがして」 Tokyo dialect?

Comment: I regard this as western dialect. http://sooda.jp/qa/64036

Comment: If so, how would you explain the use of  「いえねえ」 by the same speaker?  There is nothing western about that, is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base verb here is:

> 「嗅{か}ぐ」= "to smell something"

「かが**し**て」　is the fairly common colloquial (and slightly slangy) version of「かが**せ**て」.  This is the テ-form of 「かがせる」("***to let one smell something***"), which is in the causative form of 「かぐ」.  Please make sure you are following this because every word is important in this paragraph.

「かがして」 is not Tokyo dialect; It is used everywhere.  People say 「見{み}**し**て」 for 「見**せ**て」("Let me see."), 「食{た}べさ**し**て」 for 「食べさ**せ**て」("Let me eat".), etc. colloquially.  I do not think this is taught in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language, and I do not think J-learners should be using these until they are really fluent, either.

> "For the first time in so long, these leather gloves that have surely been sucking my opponents' blood are now letting me smell an indescribable smell."